# Suppress empty lines around `align` in latex export from `org-mode`

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

Is there an elegant way to visually set apart an `align` environment in `org-mode` but have no newlines around the environment in the LaTeX output?

The naive attempt

```
Some text.
#
\begin{align}
    1=1
\end{align}
#
More text.
```

exports to a LaTeX buffer as

```
Some text.

\begin{align}
    1=1
\end{align}

More text.
```

and the empty lines around `align` give too much vertical space to the text.

I know I could do

```
Some text.
@@latex:%@@
\begin{align}
    1=1
\end{align}
@@latex:%@@
More text.
```

but this gives no nice visual separation in the `org` buffer.

Comment: There is a very similar question that might help: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/77892/adding-some-padding-for-latex-fragments-in-org-mode - if it does, please close this one as a duplicate.

Comment: I have tried that solution and it does not change the newlines at all.

Comment: But the question is the same, correct? You should mention that the solution did not work for you as a comment on the answer to that question and link to this question. But this question *is* a duplicate and it should be closed as such (even though there is no answer that satisfied everybody yet). That way, all efforts are concentrated on *one* question and discussion is not diluted among different questions.

Comment: You are right, I flagged it as duplicate. Thanks for bringing the other question to my attention.

Comment: While [my question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/77892/adding-some-padding-for-latex-fragments-in-org-mode) is similar, and the solution I posted works somewhat for me, I much prefer to have something that adjusts the lines "visually" instead of changing the exported file, which is sort of what the OP seems to want.

Comment: Putting some comment-highlighted delimiters around the align environment in the org file would be enough visual separation for me. I've in fact enclosed all align blocks in `#+begin_export latex`-`#-end_export` pairs as a workaround, but as of the most recent update of Doom Emacs, this is not highlighting the math inside anymore...

Answer (score 1):

I've asked a similar question [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/77892/adding-some-padding-for-latex-fragments-in-org-mode) and answered myself there, but I feel like that solution is less ideal than what I had hoped, and instead wrote something better. Below is a function that should be hooked to `after-change-functions`, which checks for the delimiters `\[` and `\]`. Should these delimiters be found, the function adjusts the line vertical height visually to add the spacing required. The code is very rudimentary and needs to be expanded to handle <del>YASnippet expansions</del> and other environment blocks, but it gives the gist of what I think is the best solution.

Note that I am a novice in ELisp, so there may be some bad practices in the code below:

```
(defvar yas--snippet-being-expanded nil)
(defun org-adjust-visual-padding (beginning end _)
  "Add padding for lines between BEGINNING & END that have LaTeX delimiters."
  (unless (eq yas--snippet-being-expanded t)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char beginning)

      ;; We actually want to start at the line before, to removing the previous line's
      ;; padding if necessary.
      (forward-line -1)
      (while (and (<= (point) end) (not (eq (point-max) (point))))
        (progn
          (beginning-of-line)
          
          ;; Check the start of line for "\[" pattern.
          (if (and (looking-at "^\\\\\\[") (not (eq (line-number-at-pos) 1)))
              (progn
                (forward-line -1)
                
                ;; If pattern is found, add line spacing.
                (put-text-property (point-at-eol) (min (1- (point-max)) (1+ (point-at-eol))) 'line-spacing 10)
                (forward-line 1))

            ;; If pattern is not found, try the other delimiter.
            (progn
              (end-of-line)
              (if (>= (- (point) (point-at-bol)) 2)
                  (progn
                    (backward-char 2)
                    (if (looking-at "\\\\\\]$")

                        ;; Other delimiter was found at the end of this line.
                        (put-text-property (point-at-eol) (min (1- (point-max)) (1+ (point-at-eol))) 'line-spacing 10)
                      
                      ;; No pattern was found. Remove line spacing.
                      (remove-text-properties (point-at-eol) (min (1- (point-max)) (1+ (point-at-eol))) '(line-spacing 10))))
                
                ;; No pattern can exist here. Remove line spacing.
                (remove-text-properties (point-at-eol) (min (1- (point-max)) (1+ (point-at-eol))) '(line-spacing 10)))))

          ;; Move to the next line within the loop.
          (forward-line 1))))))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda()                                                                                                         
                           (add-hook 'after-change-functions #'org-adjust-visual-padding nil t)                                            
                           (add-hook 'yas-before-expand-snippet-hook (lambda() (setq yas--snippet-being-expanded t)) nil t)                
                           (add-hook 'yas-after-exit-snippet-hook (lambda()                                                                
                                                                    (setq yas--snippet-being-expanded nil)                                 
                                                                    (org-adjust-visual-padding yas-snippet-beg yas-snippet-end 0)) nil t)))
```

Results:

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1. I'll leave it open as it's marked for duplicate and about align. But how do you get the TeX rendered in-buffer as show in your second screenshot?

Comment: @Christoph90 In Org mode, you can run `org-preview-latex` (default binding is `C-c C-x C-l`) to render all LaTeX fragments in the section. There is a similar command for TeX mode I believe.

Comment: @Christoph90 I also use [org-fragtog](https://github.com/io12/org-fragtog) to automatically render the fragments when I exit the math environment. Note however that rendering, as of now, is not done in parallel, and so the editor freezes up when you render fragments. While there are ways around this, in the next version of Org the entire fragment rendering process has been rewritten from scratch to be much better than it is currently.

Comment: Very interesting to know, thanks for your insight! Are they anywhere tracking this feature?

Comment: Probably the [Org repository](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/).